Dockerized Nginx wont display Dockerized React application
How can I update my nginx config so the docker nginx will display my dockerized react website, both docker containers on the same host.
I can visit the react application through localhost at the published port but not directly through IP(or container name) and port of the container itself.
Nginx is up and I can hit the "welcome to nginx" page from localhost but I cannot see the react application.
Container deployment for react docker run --rm -p 8080:8000 --name hull hull-image
Container deployment for nginx docker run --rm -p 80:80 --link hull --name nginx-container nginx-reverse-proxy
access logs for nginx show access when I got to http://localhost, no errors logged.
When I docker network inspect a new network I created I see both containers on it.
nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name hull;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hull:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    }
}

Nginx Docker file
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]# Use Nginx as the production server

